# Saving ParseObject in Background terminate the app without error

Tags: android, parse-platform, aws-sdk

I'm using SDK 1.13.1

I try to save an `ParseObject` within an S3 TransferUtil callback but it crashes

```
        upload.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
                if (state == TransferState.COMPLETED) {
                    Log.i("statechange", state.toString());
                    ParseObject Book = ParseObject.create("MyOBject");
                    Book.put("user", User);
                    Book.put("bookname", "randome bookname");
                    Book.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                           // do nothing
                        }
                    });
```

But this works without passing the `SaveCallback`

```
Book.saveInBackground();
```

I'm using Android API Level 22 without Instant Run, it was working when I was running minSDK 18

logcat

```
10-28 19:08:24.286 3758-3758/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
10-28 19:08:24.404 3758-3758/org.example.app W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/org.example.app-1/lib/arm64
10-28 19:08:24.411 3758-3758/org.example.app I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
10-28 19:08:24.477 3758-3769/org.example.app I/art: humin current process: org.example.app
10-28 19:08:24.477 3758-3769/org.example.app I/art: current process_level is : 0
10-28 19:08:24.484 3758-3800/org.example.app I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
10-28 19:08:24.494 3758-3758/org.example.app I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustHwWallpaperManagerImpl
10-28 19:08:24.501 3758-3800/org.example.app I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
10-28 19:08:24.543 3758-3758/org.example.app W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
10-28 19:08:24.554 3758-3758/org.example.app I/zzai: Making Creator dynamically
10-28 19:08:24.576 3758-3769/org.example.app I/art: current process_level is : 0
10-28 19:08:24.620 3758-3758/org.example.app W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000007/n/arm64-v8a
10-28 19:08:24.628 3758-3758/org.example.app I/System.out: [/system/bin/getprop, debug.mapview.logs]
10-28 19:08:24.628 3758-3758/org.example.app I/System.out: null
10-28 19:08:24.628 3758-3758/org.example.app I/System.out: null
10-28 19:08:24.628 3758-3758/org.example.app I/System.out: Calling by::className:maps.y.D  MethodName:a
10-28 19:08:24.641 3758-3758/org.example.app W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
10-28 19:08:24.645 3758-3758/org.example.app I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 9877000
10-28 19:08:24.648 3758-3758/org.example.app I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 9877448
10-28 19:08:24.652 3758-3758/org.example.app W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
10-28 19:08:24.662 3758-3758/org.example.app W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
10-28 19:08:24.670 3758-3758/org.example.app W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
10-28 19:08:24.673 3758-3758/org.example.app I/System.out: [/system/bin/getprop, debug.mapview.gmmserver]
10-28 19:08:24.673 3758-3758/org.example.app I/System.out: null
10-28 19:08:24.673 3758-3758/org.example.app I/System.out: null
10-28 19:08:24.673 3758-3758/org.example.app I/System.out: Calling by::className:maps.y.D  MethodName:a
10-28 19:08:24.684 3758-3758/org.example.app W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
10-28 19:08:24.689 3758-3758/org.example.app W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
10-28 19:08:24.697 3758-3758/org.example.app W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
10-28 19:08:24.702 3758-3758/org.example.app W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
10-28 19:08:24.711 3758-3758/org.example.app W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
10-28 19:08:24.711 3758-3758/org.example.app W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskWriteViolation
10-28 19:08:24.711 3758-3758/org.example.app I/System.out: [/system/bin/getprop, debug.mapview.renderer]
10-28 19:08:24.711 3758-3758/org.example.app I/System.out: null
10-28 19:08:24.711 3758-3758/org.example.app I/System.out: null
10-28 19:08:24.711 3758-3758/org.example.app I/System.out: Calling by::className:maps.y.D  MethodName:a
10-28 19:08:24.723 3758-3758/org.example.app W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
10-28 19:08:24.738 3758-3758/org.example.app W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
10-28 19:08:24.739 3758-3758/org.example.app I/c: Token loaded from file. Expires in: 431972354 ms.
10-28 19:08:24.739 3758-3758/org.example.app I/c: Scheduling next attempt in 431672 seconds.
10-28 19:08:24.763 3758-3758/org.example.app W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskWriteViolation
10-28 19:08:24.763 3758-3758/org.example.app W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskWriteViolation
10-28 19:08:24.775 3758-3815/org.example.app I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
10-28 19:08:24.785 3758-3815/org.example.app I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
10-28 19:08:24.803 3758-3758/org.example.app W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
10-28 19:08:24.803 3758-3758/org.example.app W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskWriteViolation
10-28 19:08:24.803 3758-3839/org.example.app W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
10-28 19:08:24.835 3758-3758/org.example.app I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
10-28 19:08:24.837 3758-3769/org.example.app I/art: Object allocation is busy now, so prior to grow the heap. New heap size is 34 MB
10-28 19:08:24.883 3758-3843/org.example.app I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-28 19:08:24.932 3758-3769/org.example.app I/art: current process_level is : 0
10-28 19:08:24.940 3758-3866/org.example.app W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
10-28 19:08:25.003 3758-3758/org.example.app W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
10-28 19:08:25.004 3758-3758/org.example.app W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskWriteViolation
10-28 19:08:25.015 3758-3769/org.example.app I/art: current process_level is : 0
10-28 19:08:25.088 3758-3769/org.example.app I/art: current process_level is : 0
10-28 19:08:25.126 3758-3769/org.example.app I/art: current process_level is : 0
10-28 19:08:25.147 3758-3769/org.example.app I/art: current process_level is : 0
10-28 19:08:25.531 3758-3769/org.example.app I/art: current process_level is : 0
10-28 19:08:25.531 3758-3769/org.example.app I/art: Object allocation is busy now, so prior to grow the heap. New heap size is 48 MB
10-28 19:08:25.745 3758-3769/org.example.app I/art: current process_level is : 0
10-28 19:08:26.293 3758-3817/org.example.app I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
10-28 19:08:26.331 3758-3817/org.example.app I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
10-28 19:08:26.811 3758-3840/org.example.app W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
10-28 19:08:26.815 3758-3840/org.example.app I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:2
10-28 19:08:26.815 3758-3840/org.example.app I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 2

10-28 19:22:25.575 3758-16718/org.example.app E/WVMExtractor: Failed to open libwvm.so: dlopen failed: library "libwvm.so" not found
10-28 19:22:25.576 3758-16718/org.example.app I/FFMPEGExtractor: Users across the process calls!
10-28 19:22:25.608 3758-16718/org.example.app I/Utils: vstride = 0,vsliceHeight = 536870912
10-28 19:22:25.622 3758-16721/org.example.app I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
10-28 19:22:25.630 3758-16721/org.example.app W/ACodec: do not know color format 0x7f000001 = 2130706433
10-28 19:22:25.630 3758-16721/org.example.app W/ACodec: do not know color format 0x7f000005 = 2130706437
10-28 19:22:25.631 3758-16721/org.example.app W/ACodec: do not know color format 0x7f000002 = 2130706434
10-28 19:22:25.631 3758-16721/org.example.app W/ACodec: do not know color format 0x7f000006 = 2130706438
10-28 19:22:25.631 3758-16721/org.example.app W/ACodec: do not know color format 0x17 = 23
10-28 19:22:25.632 3758-16721/org.example.app W/ACodec: do not know color format 0x18 = 24
10-28 19:22:25.632 3758-16721/org.example.app W/ACodec: do not know color format 0x7f000011 = 2130706449
10-28 19:22:25.633 3758-16721/org.example.app W/ACodec: do not know color format 0x16 = 22
10-28 19:22:25.633 3758-16721/org.example.app W/ACodec: do not know color format 0x7f000007 = 2130706439
10-28 19:22:25.633 3758-16721/org.example.app W/ACodec: do not know color format 0x7f000008 = 2130706440
10-28 19:22:25.633 3758-16721/org.example.app W/ACodec: do not know color format 0x19 = 25
10-28 19:22:25.634 3758-16721/org.example.app W/ACodec: do not know color format 0x1a = 26
10-28 19:22:25.634 3758-16721/org.example.app W/ACodec: do not know color format 0x1b = 27
10-28 19:22:25.634 3758-16721/org.example.app W/ACodec: do not know color format 0x1c = 28
10-28 19:22:25.635 3758-16721/org.example.app W/ACodec: do not know color format 0x7f000003 = 2130706435
10-28 19:22:25.635 3758-16721/org.example.app W/ACodec: do not know color format 0x7f000009 = 2130706441
10-28 19:22:25.635 3758-16721/org.example.app W/ACodec: do not know color format 0x7f00000c = 2130706444
10-28 19:22:25.635 3758-16721/org.example.app W/ACodec: do not know color format 0x7f000012 = 2130706450
10-28 19:22:25.635 3758-16721/org.example.app W/ACodec: do not know color format 0x7f00000a = 2130706442
10-28 19:22:25.635 3758-16721/org.example.app W/ACodec: do not know color format 0x7f00000b = 2130706443
10-28 19:22:25.636 3758-16721/org.example.app W/ACodec: do not know color format 0x7f000789 = 2130708361
10-28 19:22:25.636 3758-16721/org.example.app I/ACodec: setupVideoEncoder succeeded
10-28 19:22:25.637 3758-16721/org.example.app W/ACodec: do not know color format 0x7f000789 = 2130708361
10-28 19:22:25.683 3758-16718/org.example.app I/Utils: vstride = 0,vsliceHeight = 536870912

                                                      [ 10-28 19:22:25.684   970:16726 E/         ]
                                                      [LocMgr] COMM thread started
10-28 19:22:25.692 3758-16731/org.example.app I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
10-28 19:22:25.696 3758-16730/org.example.app I/MediaCodec: [OMX.IMG.MSVDX.Decoder.AVC] setting surface generation to 3848193
10-28 19:22:25.697 3758-16731/org.example.app I/HwExtendedCodec: mime is [video/avc] at setVideoFormat

                                                                [ 10-28 19:22:25.697   668:31769 I/         ]
                                                                framerate = 60  
10-28 19:22:25.726 3758-16735/org.example.app I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
10-28 19:22:25.745 3758-16738/org.example.app I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
10-28 19:22:25.762 3758-16718/org.example.app I/MPEG4Writer: limits: 4294967295/0 bytes/us, bit rate: -1 bps and the estimated moov size 3193 bytes
10-28 19:22:25.798 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.0
10-28 19:22:25.810 3758-16742/org.example.app I/MPEG4Writer: setStartTimestampUs: 0
10-28 19:22:25.810 3758-16742/org.example.app I/MPEG4Writer: Earliest track starting time: 0
10-28 19:22:25.829 3758-16743/org.example.app I/MPEG4Writer: setStartTimestampUs: 0
10-28 19:22:25.842 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.0110684664625661
10-28 19:22:25.878 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.02420818257723351
10-28 19:22:25.898 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.040888811578068465
10-28 19:22:25.918 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.056047870860005566
10-28 19:22:25.956 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.07087002504870582
10-28 19:22:25.985 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.0867033119955469
10-28 19:22:26.005 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.09957848594489285
10-28 19:22:26.045 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.11543181185638741
10-28 19:22:26.067 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.12533231283050378
10-28 19:22:26.105 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.13989145560812694
10-28 19:22:26.131 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.15926106317840244
10-28 19:22:26.170 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.17748316170331202
10-28 19:22:26.208 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.19515474533815752
10-28 19:22:26.241 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.2116205121068745
10-28 19:22:26.274 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.2269898413581965
10-28 19:22:26.310 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.2449816309490676
10-28 19:22:26.358 3758-3769/org.example.app I/art: current process_level is : 0
10-28 19:22:26.363 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.26237350403562487
10-28 19:22:26.407 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.27853145004174784
10-28 19:22:26.463 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.2967907041469524
10-28 19:22:26.504 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.31258377400500975
10-28 19:22:26.545 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.3305414695240746
10-28 19:22:26.593 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.3485580295018091
10-28 19:22:26.640 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.3668126913442805
10-28 19:22:26.683 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.38519106596159197
10-28 19:22:26.727 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.4031116059003618
10-28 19:22:26.761 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.4196870303367659
10-28 19:22:26.801 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.44030114110770946
10-28 19:22:26.853 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.45832396326189817
10-28 19:22:26.881 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.47652755357639853
10-28 19:22:26.921 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.4917979404397439
10-28 19:22:26.964 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.5098484553298079
10-28 19:22:26.998 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.5242190370164208
10-28 19:22:27.038 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.5415228221541887
10-28 19:22:27.077 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.5568412190370164
10-28 19:22:27.122 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.5725090453659895
10-28 19:22:27.168 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.5906569718897856
10-28 19:22:27.211 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.6059025883662678
10-28 19:22:27.249 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.6247339270804342
10-28 19:22:27.295 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.6408007236292792
10-28 19:22:27.337 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.6611829947119399
10-28 19:22:27.378 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.6770378513776789
10-28 19:22:27.423 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.6974185917060951
10-28 19:22:27.456 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.7162173671026997
10-28 19:22:27.495 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.7338133871416643
10-28 19:22:27.537 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.7491068744781519
10-28 19:22:27.581 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.764751461174506
10-28 19:22:27.622 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.7808367659337601
10-28 19:22:27.665 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.796563317561926
10-28 19:22:27.697 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.8177187586974672
10-28 19:22:27.739 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.8355605343723908
10-28 19:22:27.786 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.8534069023100472
10-28 19:22:27.827 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.8662188978569441
10-28 19:22:27.982 3758-3758/org.example.app W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskWriteViolation
10-28 19:22:27.986 3758-16789/org.example.app W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
10-28 19:22:28.017 3758-3769/org.example.app I/art: current process_level is : 0
10-28 19:22:28.017 3758-3769/org.example.app I/art: GC statistics: 10 time(s), freed 107231(47MB) objects, paused 13.453ms total 268.982ms
10-28 19:22:28.017 3758-3769/org.example.app I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8999(376KB) AllocSpace objects, 18(1368KB) LOS objects, 23% free, 25MB/33MB, paused 6.019ms total 98.736ms at HeapTaskDaemon thread CareAboutPauseTimes 1
10-28 19:22:28.032 3758-3758/org.example.app I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 9877448
10-28 19:22:28.033 3758-3758/org.example.app W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
10-28 19:22:28.033 3758-3758/org.example.app W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskWriteViolation
10-28 19:22:28.043 3758-3758/org.example.app W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
10-28 19:22:28.043 3758-16795/org.example.app W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
10-28 19:22:28.043 3758-3758/org.example.app W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskWriteViolation
10-28 19:22:28.045 3758-16797/org.example.app W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
10-28 19:22:28.060 3758-3818/org.example.app I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
10-28 19:22:28.061 3758-3815/org.example.app I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
10-28 19:22:28.066 3758-3815/org.example.app I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
10-28 19:22:28.068 3758-3818/org.example.app I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
10-28 19:22:28.114 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.8870047314222098
10-28 19:22:28.214 3758-3765/org.example.app W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.824ms
10-28 19:22:28.215 3758-3769/org.example.app I/art: current process_level is : 0
10-28 19:22:28.215 3758-3769/org.example.app I/art: [ 10-28 19:22:28.218   970:16802 E/         ]
                                                   [LocMgr] COMM thread started
10-28 19:22:28.254 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.9054479543556917
10-28 19:22:28.255 3758-3769/org.example.app I/art: Object allocation is busy now, so prior to grow the heap. New heap size is 41 MB
10-28 19:22:28.314 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.9185443918730866
10-28 19:22:28.325 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.9348106039521291
10-28 19:22:28.379 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.9471216253826886
10-28 19:22:28.407 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.9666842471472308
10-28 19:22:28.437 3758-3769/org.example.app I/art: current process_level is : 0
10-28 19:22:28.448 3758-3758/org.example.app W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
10-28 19:22:28.449 3758-3758/org.example.app W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskWriteViolation
10-28 19:22:28.456 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing progress: 0.9782129139994433
10-28 19:22:28.463 3758-16742/org.example.app I/MPEG4Writer: Received total/0-length (216/1) buffers and encoded 216 frames. - Video
10-28 19:22:28.467 3758-16743/org.example.app I/MPEG4Writer: Received total/0-length (166/1) buffers and encoded 166 frames. - Audio
10-28 19:22:28.467 3758-16743/org.example.app I/MPEG4Writer: Audio track drift time: 0 us
10-28 19:22:28.470 3758-16718/org.example.app I/MPEG4Writer: The mp4 file will not be streamable.
10-28 19:22:28.558 3758-3758/org.example.app I/compressing: Compressing is done
10-28 19:22:28.558 3758-3758/org.example.app I/uploadfile: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/org.example.app/files/outputs/transcode_test-1868344915.mp4
10-28 19:22:28.607 3758-3758/org.example.app I/progress: 0

 [ 10-28 19:22:28.644   537:  824 I/         ]
 [getTotalMemory] total memory =2860228KB

 [ 10-28 19:22:28.655   537:  824 I/         ]
 HwCamMem mempoolcfg void android::MTMemoryPool::dumpMemInfo() Free=988600, Total=2860228, Pss=7076 mTimeOutCount=1
10-28 19:22:28.730 3758-16815/org.example.app I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
10-28 19:22:28.740 3758-16815/org.example.app I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
10-28 19:22:28.991 3758-3816/org.example.app I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
10-28 19:22:29.144 3758-3816/org.example.app I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
10-28 19:22:29.322 3758-3758/org.example.app I/progress: 100
10-28 19:22:29.408 3758-3758/org.example.app I/progress: 100
10-28 19:22:29.408 3758-3758/org.example.app I/progress: 100
10-28 19:22:29.465 3758-3758/org.example.app I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3758 SIG: 9
```

Run Log

```
I/art: current process_level is : 0
I/progress: 100
I/progress: 100
I/progress: 100
I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 32382 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Comment: You're aware that parse will be discontinued by the end of the year, right ?

Comment: Can you post the logcat output ?

Comment: Yeah i'm using a self-hosted parse backend, ok i will

Comment: @ChristopheCVB I add the logcat

Comment: @ChristopheCVB I updated

Comment: Where is the crash part ? There is no error in that log...

Comment: @ChristopheCVB yeah it only appear under "Run" which says `application terminated.`